# Symfony Requirements Checker returns 404 Not found

Tags: symfony, docker, nginx, nginx-config

I am about to create a Symfony project with docker and php-fpm like this tutorial: [Jobeet](https://jobeet-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

My Symfony is running and I can see changes when I visit http://127.0.0.1
all looks fine.

But when I want to run the Symfony requirements checker I get a 404 Not Found exception from Nginx in the browser.

I am pretty sure it's a problem with my nginx.conf file. So I post it here:

```
server {
    listen 80 default;

    client_max_body_size 520M;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/application.access.log;

    root /application/public;

    # Deny all . files
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_index app.php;
        send_timeout 1800;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 1800;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/application_php_errors.log";
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    # Statics
    location /(bundles|media) {
        access_log off;
        expires 30d;
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }
}
```

I was guessing it is this part:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    return 404;
}
```

But when I comment it out, Symfony starts to download the PHP file.

What might be the problem with this `nginx.conf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is related to your other configuration block containing the call to the php-fpm:

```
location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
```

You can change it to:

```
location ~ ^/.+\.php(/|$) {
```

This will tell nginx to pass all access to php files via the php-fpm. You can then remove the block which throws a 404 whenever a php script is called that is not the index.php

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    return 404;
}
```

You version is the one recommended by Symfony and will make sure that only your front controller (index.php) is ever accessible from the outside, which is reasonable for a new Symfony project. Since you should not expose the `check.php` on production anyway, I would recommend keeping your setup for the production environment.

In summary this could be your config for development:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/html/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/.+\.php(/|$) {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param APP_ENV dev;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
    }
}
```